# Typescript: Load content of file in variable

Tags: typescript

**I have a js file defining an object:**

```
var schema = {
    "date": Date.now(),
    "someOtherField": 5 + 6,
    "aMoreComplexField: {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Now in my typescript code I want to load this file and want to have the content of the variable schema in a variable.

**Pseudocode**:

```
function loadSchema(schemaFile1, anotherSchemaFile) {
    let schema = someHowLoadFile(schemaFile);
    schema = Object.assign(schema, someHowLoadFile(anotherSchemaFile));

    // do some additional stuff here with content of schema

    return schema;
}
```

But how can I achieve this? I can define the content of the schema file so if the content should be something else than `var schema = {}` just tell me what to do. I tried to put `export {}` and `return {}` but my IDE directly shows me that this is not correct.
As logic is called in the schema like the `Date.now()` I can't just use a JSON file.

Comment: Try javascript `eval()` function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

You can try exporting the content of that file as a constant and then import in your component.

create schema.ts

```
export const SCHEMA = {
"date": Date.now(),
"someOtherField": 5 + 6,
"aMoreComplexField: {
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

}

then import and use.
For example, in your app.ts:

```
import { SCHEMA } from 'schema.ts';

console.log('date is', SCHEMA.date);
```

Comment: This will not work in my use case as there are multiple files and a string tells me which file to load. Also I have to load 2 files and merge their content with Object.assign()

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying out several ways, how to best outsource the constants, because what a miracle, I found out that a larger use of constants is simplifying the code, and improving its quality in almost every sense. For the sake of an easy overview and future flexibility, I want them be centralized in a separate file or folder, but how to do this in the most efficient way?

XML is outdated trough JSON, what is not satisfying too, a very narrow standard, allowing nothing but basic data types, and extremely delicate. The worst point is to loose Typescript's type-definitions and -checking, what is providing a specially great service for such, preventing mistakes, and intellisense for supporting my aging brain. Therefore, there is a great desire to write the outsourced parts as Typescript objects, and for their usage, to load them into any variables of any other scripts.

A `<script>` element can't be used, for it's not providing any access to its content, nor allowing any influence over how to be integrated, nor would be available in a DOM-less context. The same thing is to say about a secondary `<document>` object and the `DomParser`, far to complicated and worthless for such usage. The known module systems are a little bit better, but their benefits are far outnumbered by their precedences, restrictions and need of understanding all combined, not an easy way too, in my opinion not appropriate for browsers.

I found a great way, absolutely simple, neither needing any of the tings above, nor any special knowledge, can comfortably be monitored and debugged, allowing every kind of flexibility, to place the data where it's being wanted, accessing any kind of script or module types, using robust old fashion basic technology, working on every browser version up to more than 10 years back, taking only a single statement in a single short line, and of corse, not only working with constants, but with everything thinkable.

**The magic word is `Function()` with a capital 'F'**

First, we need to have the content of the script-file loaded as a string, in Node trough `fs.readFileSync()`, or in a browser trough the `httpRequest` object, or an `Electron.ipcXXX` object, or whatever else. Let's say this is already done, and the file looks like this, in my case a structure of constants.

```
var script : string; // holding the content of the file
```

containing something like

```
"defs = {set1: {a: 1, b: 2}, set2: {a: 3, b: 4}}"
```

the local target where to place the payload

```
var defs = {}; // an empty object to be filled
```

being applied trough

```
Function("defs", script)(defs);
```

Magic Magic, when debugging this, a new tab will be opened, showing a temporary script, named something like 'VM123' containing the created function named 'anonymous' with the argument named 'defs', containing the entire content of the loaded script file, what had been passed in the first set of arguments, and we are jumping back. This far it is syntactically accepted, will be executed, and we are jumping in again, observing how it's working out. This time, it is using the second set of arguments, in this case the provided empty target object, and voila, afterwards it will be filled with what we wanted.

The only restriction is, that in the loaded script, the same variables **must not** be declared, such would replace the passed ones, resulting in an empty result.

**neither** `"var defs = {…}"` **nor** `"const defs = {…}"` **nor** `"let defs = {…}"`

**but only** `"defs = {…}"`

In Javascript, such a name is being accepted without any declaration, but in Typescript, the typechecker would protest, could either be silenced trough `//@ts-ignore` or much better be satisfied trough `declare var defs;`.

But what is when my structure of constants is needing some context, using some other constants, looking something like this?

```
"defs = {set1: {a: arr[2], b: 2}, set2: {a: 3, b: arr[5]}}"
```

This ain't getting any harder than before, only needs a second argument, the required array named 'arr', that won't be affected, but is only providing the needed context.

```
var arr = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];

Function("defs", "arr", script)(defs, arr);
```

This method is working excellently with everything what I've tried, such as compiled from Typescript, I guess just everything thinkable everywhere. When executing Typescript compiled stuff, it is filling the target objects memberwise, allowing to get them mixed with others if wanted, or keeping them separated, depending on the chosen target. Or in other words, it is unbinding from the given names and/or types, offering another dimension of conception, a really a great vision.

If there are subobjects embeded, some objects inside of objects, they can be passed in advance or not, if the loaded script is dealing optionally with them, as can be seen in every compilation:

```
…(arg || arg = {})…
```

This is currently overthrowing and revolutionizing my understanding and thinking about the file concepts, rising the harder questions, why even to work with any modules any longer, why even having wasted time having learned about them?

Have fun.